# Threejs - Best way to render image texture only in a portion of the mesh

Tags: svg, three.js, shader, textures

I have the .obj of a T-Shirt, it contains a few meshes and materials and I'm coloring it using a `CanvasTexture` fed by an inline svg.

Now I should add a logo at a specific location (more or less above the heart), but I'm struggling to understand which is the best/proper way of doing it (I'm quite new to 3D graphics and Three.js). This is what I tried so far:

- since I'm coloring the T-Shirt through a `CanvasTexture` fed by an inline svg, I thought it would have been easy to just draw the logo into the svg at specific coordinates. And it was easy indeed, but the logo gets not rendered (or is not visible in some way) on the texture/mesh, although it is visible in the inline svg. So `CanvasTexture` probably doesn't work with embedded images (I tried both base64 and URL)
- so, I started looking into more 3d "native" ways of doing it, but I haven't found one that really makes sense to me. I know there's `ShaderMaterial` in threejs, which I could use to selectively render pixels of the logo or pixels of the cloth, but that means making a lot of complex computation to figure out where the logo should be and I can't believe drawing a simple JPEG or PNG with specific coordinates and size can be so complex... I must have missed an obvious solution.

**EDIT**

Here is how I'm adding the image to the inline svg (option 1 above).

1. Add the image to the inline svg

```js
const groups = Array.from(svg.querySelectorAll('g'));
// this is the "g" tag where I want to add the logo into
const targetGroup = groups.find((group: SVGGElement) => group.getAttribute('id') === "logo_placeholder");

const image = document.createElement('image');
image.setAttribute('width', '64');
image.setAttribute('height', '64');
image.setAttribute('x', '240');
image.setAttribute('y', '512');
image.setAttribute('xlink:href', `data:image/png;base64,${base64}`);

targetGroup.appendChild(image);
```

2. Draw inline svg to 2d canvas

```js
static drawSvgToCanvas = async (canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, canvasSize: TSize, svgString: string) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    canvas.width = canvasSize.width;
    canvas.height = canvasSize.height;

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const image = new Image(); // eslint-disable-line no-undef
    image.src = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(svgString)}`;
    image.onload = () => {
      if (ctx) {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
          resolve();
        } else {
          reject(new Error('2D context is not set on canvas'));
        }
      };

    image.onerror = () => {
      reject(new Error('Could not load svg image'));
    }
 });
};
```

3. Draw 2d canvas to threejs Texture

```js
const texture = new Three.CanvasTexture(canvas);
texture.mapping = Three.UVMapping; // it's the default
texture.wrapS = Three.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = Three.RepeatWrapping; // it's the default
texture.magFilter = Three.LinearFilter; // it's the default
texture.minFilter = Three.LinearFilter;
texture.needsUpdate = true;

[...add texture to material...]
```

Comment: Please show some code. Do you render the SVG onto a `canvas` which you then give to the `CanvasTexture`? If so, try rendering in two steps: First, render the SVG on the canvas, and then render the image on top of that (on the same canvas).

Comment: @Sphinxxx thank you in advance for the help, please see my edit. Actually I'm not rendering the image "on top" of the canvas, I'm just adding it to the inline svg, which is then drawn to 2d canvas (and then the 2d canvas is drawn to a texture). It's working great for paths/colors, but not for images ....

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested to do it in two steps. For some reason, canvases don't like SVGs with embedded images, so for a similar project I had to render the SVG and the image separately, on the same canvas.

Comment: @Sphinxxx that worked! This is a step forward for me, so thank you (you can answer the question). It's disappointing to see that Canvas doesn't work with embedded images though, as I also need to let the user move the logo around the T-Shirt. And I can't move it because there's no way to reference the drawn image... removing and re-drawing the whole svg + image at each movement is far from ideal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, canvases don't like SVGs with embedded images, so for a similar project I had to do this in two steps, rendering the SVG and the image separately:

First, render the SVG on the canvas, and then render the image on top of that (on the same canvas).

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(imgSVG, 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(img2, 130, 10, 65, 90);

const texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0f9hm7gx/